# Changes to Javascript files don't take effect in VS

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, internet-explorer, visual-web-developer

I have a web site being opened in Web Developer. Whenever I make a change to a JS file that is a part of the site and run the site in WebDev, the changes do not take effect.

Using the IE tools, you can see the JS file does not have the changes made to it. Closing and re-opening VS or refeshing the page the in IE does not work.

Any ideas? I'm stuck and it seems a rather silly thing.

Comment: You use Visual Studio for *anything* ?

Comment: @Pointy: No, you've got it wrong. It's Visual Web Developer that sucks. Visual Basic and Visual C# are great.

Comment: Ctrl+F5 to force a refresh from the "server".

Comment: @minitech yes sorry brain issue here - my eyes saw "VS" but my brain saw "VSS" and everything's hazy after that point :-)

Comment: If you use google chrome, you can disable caching so you don't have to keep Ctrl+F5ing during development.